# REST URI definition

Tags: rest, uri

I can't get comfortable with defining 'good REST' URIs. The scenario is an existing site with products for sale. You can view data in a number of views, drilling down a hierarchy, but basically `cat1/cat/ products`, or `cat 2/cat3/products` or any combination of categories 1 to 4. The other products view is based on a search.

How do you form the URI's?

```
products/??????
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use use a query string in your URI:

```
/products?categories=german,adult,foo,bar
```

In order to avoid multiple URIs you could enforce some logic like alphabetical ordering of categories on the server side so a request to the above URI would actually redirect via a 301 Moved Permanently response to:

```
/products?categories=adult,bar,foo,german
```

For that above query part pattern to work in browsers you will have to use JavaScript to generate the query from any html forms - you could, alternatively, do it like this if you wanted to avoid that particular problem:

```
/products?cat1=adult&cat2=bar&cat3=foo&cat4=german
```

Comment: mike, that is my natural approach.  It aslo fits for searches too

products?cat1=adult&cat2=bar&cat3=foo&cat4=german
products?cat2=bar&cat3=foo&cat4=german
products?search=german books

I know this gives me the parameters to find the list of products to return.  Im ok with this but concerned I'm missing something from the more hierarchical url samples /products/cat1/{cat1}/...

Comment: It doesn't matter - as long as it has a URI, you can link to it

Comment: That idea of redirecting the URIs to alternates with 'better' query strings seems redundant to me. Server side, you would read out this collection of 'categories' and you can just cache the search there. Of course, with some client side JS, it's trivial enough to help by also doing the same order for the request.

Answer (score 1):

Having designed a site that follows the principles of the REST architecture, my advice is to base your decision on your URI structure solely on your server design, that is how your server will parse an incoming URI and deliver the corresponding resource.

One principle of REST design (as I see it) is that your users/clients will NEVER have to form a URL to find a resource, they will instead read some hypertext (i.e. HTML) which describes resources, identify what they want, and get the appropriate link from the hypertext (for example, in HTML, the href attribute of the  tag holds the URL, which could just as well be a random string of characters.

Again, in my opinion, if your application requires that a user/client be able to perform searches for arbitrarily named categories, it's probably not suitable to have a RESTfully designed interface.

Comment: As long as the rules are well defined in the definition of the media type it is ok to do some uri construction, such as with a URI template.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the problem here is that you don't have a unique ID for the resource because:

```
products/cat1/cat4
```

Is actually the same page as

```
products/cat4/cat1
```

(Presumably a view of everything tagged with cat1 and cat4, or all matches from cat1 and cat4)

If your categories where organised into a hierarchy you would know that "cat6" is a child of "cat1", for example.

So your two options would be

1) Enforce a natural order for the categories

or

2) Have two different URI's essentially pointing to the same resource (with a 301 permanant redirect to your preferred resource).

Comment: thanks Sohnee, in this case the top cat is Language, the second can change, and so on, for example, ../French/Independent/Primary or /German/assisted learning/adult, but another way in might be German/adult.  Is the uri structure required too dynamic?  To me it was a much like a search, but with 4 terms with no hierarchy - which doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: There should only be one URI that returns 200 OK along with the representation.  The other URI can return a 302 See Other.

Comment: @DarrelMiller there's nothing really wrong with multiple URIs referring to the same resource. Plus, reading OP's comment here, sounds more like these are not just interchangeable tags, but categories and sub-categories. ie he wants URIs like `/products/shoes/skateshoes/black/size10` (not the best URI, but should serve the idea)